# How to check if value exist in json file using php?

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        $file = 'entries.json';
        $json_file = file_get_contents($file);
        $parsed_json = json_decode($json_file, true);
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $flag = false;
        foreach ($parsed_json as $key => $value) 
        {
            if ($value['email'] == $email) 
            {
                $flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($flag) 
        {
            $arr = array(
                "centre" => $_POST['centre'],
                "name" => $_POST['name'],
                "email" => $_POST['email'],
                "phone" => $_POST['phone'],
                "city" => $_POST['city'],
                "course" => $_POST['course']
            );
            $json_string = json_encode($arr);
            $success = file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
            if($success == true)
            {
                echo "<p class='text-success'>Thank you for showing interest. Please contact your counsellor for Unique Registration Number (URN)<p>";
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "<p class='text-danger'>Email already exist.<p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

In the above code I am trying to validate with `email id already exist` when we post form data in json format. Here, Json format working perfectly but it always show `thank you message`. If email exist or not.

When I click on submit then all data post and convert in json successfully and I am fetching this data in other website but I want to show here that `email id already exist`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You use a database instead of json file

Comment: Output is working as expected since didn't do any check on mail before post it. First you need to query the db(or storage) with given email and see if exits. If duplicate notify use and do not post ...

Comment: And you're overwriting the data in your file so your code just replacing the old entry with a new one

Comment: if data are stored in file, then open the file, iterate each records(json), check mail . (duplicate notify user, fine update file)

Comment: Agree with Alon Eitan  and Traian GEICU both

Comment: I have change in my code. Please take a look at once. Email ID exist msg work but If I enter different email id then it again show `email already exist`.

Comment: please check by code once again @AlonEitan

Comment: if said `flag=true` when mail is found then condition for adding is opposite `if(!flag) then add else duplicate`